# Load Multiple items from an excel sheet into a listview c#

Tags: c#, excel, listview

I am desperately trying to add multiple items from an excel sheet into a listview using c#. I have looked all over the Internet for a working solution but still no result.

I would like to ask anybody who knows about c#'s listview for an helping hand...

Thanks in advance

code so far:-

```
public void InitializeListView(string path) {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wx = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
        int count = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        Excel.Range userrange = wx.UsedRange;
        count = userrange.Rows.Count;
        statusBar1.Panels[1].Text = "Amount: " + count;

        for (row = 1; row <= count; row++) {
            for (col = 1; col <= 4; col++) {
                listView1.Items.Add(wx.Cells[row, col].Value2);
                listView1.Items.Add(wx.Cells[row, col].Value2);
                listView1.Items.Add(wx.Cells[row, col].Value2);
                listView1.Items.Add(wx.Cells[row, col].Value2);
            }
        }
        sheet.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excel.Quit();
    }//------------------ end of InitializeListView -------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you please see https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/460391/Retrieve-datas-from-Excel-Sheet-to-Listview

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method. Please look if it helps you.
1. Convert the Excel file in to .csv and Store it in the a Path
2. Take the data from .csv file to list.
3. Delete the .csv file once all data is loaded in List<>.

To Read from .csv

```
       string filepath = "D:\\sample.csv";
       var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\sample.csv").Length;
       int TotalLines = Int32.Parse(lineCount.ToString());
       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
       string line;
       List<string> lstSample = new List<string>();

       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           lstSample = line.Split(',').ToList();
       }
```